# indexoutofboundsexception index 0 size 0

Tags: android, android-studio, geolocalización, map

Tengo un codigo que tiene que devolverme las coordenadas y la direccion de las coordenadas de mi dispocitivo y del lugar que seleccione en el mapa, la aplicacion me da las coordenadas de mi dispositivo redondeada, pero no me devuelve la direccion, en vez de eso lo que me devuelve es un error:
 ***"java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:0 Size:0"***

Pero al seleccionar un lugar en el mapa me devuelve las coordenadas completa y tambien su direccion.

Este es el codigo:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);
        myplacebtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.myplacebtn);//Button --get my location

        myplacebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (validatePermissionsLocation()) {
                    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        return;
                    }

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                           LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                            MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                            new MyLocationListener()
                    );

                        showCurrentLocation();

                }
            }
        });
//creando Mapa
   mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //get a MapView
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {


        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            map = googleMap;
   //Crea Marcador en el Lugar Seleccionado en el Mapa
            // Setting a click event handler for the map
            map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

                    //Make the Address

                    getAddress(latLng);

                }
            });
            map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

            LatLng jerusalem = new LatLng(32.1105435, 34.8683683);
            CameraUpdate miLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(jerusalem, 11);
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(jerusalem));
            googleMap.animateCamera(miLocation);
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(jerusalem);

           if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


               return;
               }

                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        }
    });

return view;
}

 private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
           // gpsDialog();

           startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

    }

//Ubicacion de mi dispositivo
 protected void showCurrentLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

           return;
        }
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


        if (location != null) {
            //setCoordinates.setText(location.getLatitude() + " , " + 
      location.getLongitude());

            LatLng latLng=new 
      LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

            //Make Address
           getAddress(latLng);

            CameraUpdate miLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11);

            map.animateCamera(miLocation);

        }


    }
//Metodo que devuelve direccion y coordenadas
private void getAddress(LatLng latLng){
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<android.location.Address> direccion = null;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
     // Creating a marker
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    try {
        direccion = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1); // 1 representa la cantidad de resultados a obtener

        String address = direccion.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        String city = direccion.get(0).getLocality();
        // Setting the title for the marker.
        // This will be displayed on taping the marker
        markerOptions.title(city + " : " + address);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " , " + latLng.longitude);

    }
    catch (Exception e){

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " , " + latLng.longitude);
    }


    // Setting the position for the marker
    markerOptions.position(latLng);

    setCoordinates.setText(latLng.latitude + " , " + latLng.longitude);
    latitude = latLng.latitude;
    longitude = latLng.longitude;





    // Clears the previously touched position
    map.clear();

    // Animating to the touched position
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Placing a marker on the touched position
    map.addMarker(markerOptions);


}
```

Comment: El error lo debes tener en la línea direccion.get(0).getAddressLine(0) pero puede que sea tanto al hacer el get(0) como el getAddressLine(0). Pon algunas comprobaciones antes para ver qué cantidad de registros tienen. Algo como direccion.size() y direccion.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex()

Comment: Bueno estuve revisando y al parecer el mapa de Google no reconoce la dirección en donde yo me encuentro por que al cambiar de lugar me reconoció la dirección donde se encontraba el dispocitivo

Comment: Eso era pues, que el resultado (direccion) no contenía ningún registro y, por tanto, al intentar acceder al primer elemento con get(0) te daba ese error de outofbounds

Comment: En la aplicacion de Google maps si conoce la dirección, eso quiere decir que la dirección está registrada en Google , entonces como la dirección no contiene ningún registro?

Comment: No lo sé, quizás no usen la misma base de datos, quizás le estés pasando mal las coordenadas, ni idea

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que las coordenadas existen pero estas pueden no tener datos de dirección registrados, te recomiendo validar este caso.

Ejemplo:

```
...
...
try {
        direccion = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1); // 1 representa la cantidad de resultados a obtener

        if(direccion.size() > 0){

           String address = direccion.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
           String city = direccion.get(0).getLocality();
           // Setting the title for the marker.
           // This will be displayed on taping the marker
           markerOptions.title(city + " : " + address);

        }else{
           //No se encontraron datos de dirección relacionado a la geo posicion.
        }

} catch (IOException e) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " , " + latLng.longitude);

    }

        ...
        ...
```